# My visual basic 6 translates into Portuguese Boolean variables when I concatenate with string to insert into a database table

Tags: vb6

My visual basic 6 translates into Portuguese Boolean variables when I concatenate with string to insert into a database table.

Example:
"Updata tableX set value =" & true

As vb6 interprets:
"Updata tableX set value = verdadeiro"

In Portuguese true is verdadeiro, which causes the error to insert into the database

Comment: What are you using as a backend? You may just want to "set value = 1" instead.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as a backend? If SQL Server, you may just want to:

```
 "Update tableX set value = " & iif(value, 1, 0)
```

instead.

Alternatively, if you can use:

```
 "Update tableX set value = " & iif(value, "true", "false")
```

Which is essentially a compacted if statement. This will take take string conversion out of the mix, which is what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216379) of Visual Basic 6:

> When Boolean constants or variables are concatenated into a string and the Regional Setting is not English, Visual Basic 6.0 coerces the Boolean value to a string containing the text of the value. For example, when the Regional Settings are set to French, you would see the string "Vrai" for True. Unfortunately, "Vrai" will not be converted back to the Boolean True even when CBool is applied. If CBool is applied to the string containing the localized word, a Type Mismatch error occurs.

It was fixed in Service Pack 3

> This bug was corrected in Visual Studio 6.0 Service Pack 3.

I recommend to install all available updates:

- [Service Pack 6 for Visual Basic 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721)
- [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7030)

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly calling the `CStr()` function, which is *locale aware*.

Maybe try:

```
"Updata tableX set value = " & Str$(True)
```

The `Str$()` function always uses the Invariant Locale.

Er, or just:

```
"Updata tableX set value = True"
```